# Javascript make object literal equal {} inside in the function,

Tags: javascript, object, scope, object-literal

[How to understand this output?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dns6.png)

Why data.value is still equal to 'value'?

```js
function funcA(data) {
  data.key = 'data';
}

function funcB(data) {
  data = {};
  data.value = 'data';
}
var data = {
  key: 'key',
  value: 'value'
};

funcA(data);
funcB(data);
console.log(data.key); //data
console.log(data.value); //value
```

Please help. I do not know how to understand this question.
Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Because you did this -> `data = {};`  this will create a new object, rather than change the existing instance..

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand how objects are passed in JavaScript functions. It's a reference to an object in memory that's being passed. Once you do `data = {}` in `funcB`, the function's *local copy of the reference* `data` now points to a new, empty object, not the original location of `data` as defined outside of the function. Then the line `data.value = 'data'` simply modifies that local, empty object, not the original object.

Answer (score 1):

This `data = {};` just updates the local parameter, not the original variable.

If JS was a *"pass by reference"* language, that would work, but it isn't. You're passing a *"reference type"*, but are passing it *"by value"*, so only the value (the object's reference) gets updated to a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are passed by value, but the *names* of arguments are not the same as the values. In your `funcB()` you have a couple things going on that are confusing because the names are all the same.

```
function funcB(data) {
  // the **name** `data` is not the same as the data you declared earlier
  // even though they both point to the same object
  // this inner data shadows the outer data

  data = {};
  // now you set the inner `data` name to point to a new object and you have two datas
  // one outside that you set with var data and this one. Since you can only have one
  // data name in the scope the inner one wins.
  data.value = 'data';
  // changing data here only changes the inner one.
}
```

It's easier to see if you use distinct names:

```js
function funcB(inner_data) {
  // the name inner_data and data both point to the same object
  console.log(inner_data === data)

  // now inner_data points to something else
  inner_data = {};
  inner_data.value = 'data';

}
var data = {
  key: 'key',
  value: 'value'
};

funcB(data);
console.log(data.key); //data
console.log(data.value); //value
```

The confusion happens because if you didn't name your argument `data` you could still access the outer `data` from the function. For example:

```js
function funcB(inner_data) {
  // the name inner_data and data both point to the same object
  console.log(inner_data === data)

  // but since you're not shadowing the outer data with 
  // a new name in this scope you can still reach outer data
  data = {};
  data.value = 'data';

}
var data = {
  key: 'key',
  value: 'value'
};

funcB(data);
console.log(data.key); //data
console.log(data.value); //value
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should already know that when u assign an object to a variable this variable will hold a reference to this object's data in the memory

a reference is nothing but a memory location so that we know where the data of the object is stored

js has something called [Call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) , i had troubles understating it but after a little search my conclusion was :

if you just **changed property of an object** inside a function scope , it will affect the variable globally (outside the function scope) cause u changed the values of the object that this variable is referencing not the reference itself , like your funcA

unless you **re-assigned a new object** to this variable, in this case you are changing where your variable referencing , its now referencing to something else so any change you do to it inside the function will not affect the variable values outside the function , funcB doesn't affect the variable globally (outside of the function scope)  because it creates a new local object with a new reference which is scoped to the function only

as for primitive types they will always be pass by value , so any changes made to them will only affect the variable in the scope of the function making the change